# What is the invention in the application?

Tags: prior-art-request

In reference to the patent: [WO2017189593A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2017189593A1)

The application is super simple, obvious and below is the list of opensource code as evidence which responses to the intent

http://github.com/paralax/awesome-honeypots is a list of open source honey-pots which responses to the intent.

Answer (score 1):

The “invention” is always defined by the claims. In this case there are 39 claims (technically 39 separate but related inventions).  1, 14, and 27 are independent claims (with the dependent claims incorporating all limitations of the claims they depend on (plus whatever limitations they add making them more narrow).  Independent claims in an application are typically very broad and are typically narrowed during prosecution to one of the more narrow depedent claims or by adding additional limitations from the specfication.  Thus, I would expect that the independent claims not to be allowed if already disclosed before the priority date of this patent application, with some more narrow version ultimately being granted if something is actually patentable.